# RegistryKey.SetValue breaking PATH

Tags: .net, path, registry, environment

I'm trying to add my application path to the system environment path, and while the following code does append it appropriately:

```
    using (RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\", true)) {
      String pathString = regKey.GetValue("PATH", "", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames).ToString();
      if (pathString[pathString.Length - 1] != ';') {
        pathString = pathString + ";";
      }
      regKey.SetValue("PATH", pathString + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ";");
    }
```

it will not take effect until I look at the environment variables via Control Panel, and then when I do, it will break all other environment variable references in that path, like %SystemRoot%\System32 until... I copy the entire path string out of and back into PATH variable and re-save it.

So there is apparently some piece that I am missing, because the path is 100% correct, it just seems like it hasn't been updated against the system.

Edit: I have found that changing:

```
regKey.SetValue("PATH", pathString + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ";");
```

To:

```
regKey.SetValue("PATH", pathString + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ";", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
```

Will fix the issue of the breaking reference variables (not sure why I need to do this, they key is already of type REG_EXPAND_SZ and I'm not changing it), but I still have the issue of the path not being refreshed until I edit it via Control Panel.

So far I have not found a programmatic way to do this.

Comment: And yes, before anyone asks, I am starting new fresh instances of command prompts to test the environment path, nothing is applied until I access the path from the Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables.

Comment: This is more of a Windows and .NET issue than a C#-7.0 issue, right?

Comment: Have you tried [System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_)

Comment: Yes this is a .NET issue (I updated the tags). I actually started with SetEnvironmentVariable, but there was no way to prevent it from expanding the reference variables (which could drastically change the length of the path) so I opted to go the RegistryKey route which gave me the option to not expand the reference variables.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so with a little R&D, it appears I need broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to windows. I was able to achieve this by importing the user32.dll function SendMessageTimeout as such:

```
class NativeMsg {

  public static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
  public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
  public static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
  public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
  public static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
  public static readonly IntPtr HWND_MESSAGE = new IntPtr(-3);

  public enum WindowsMessages : UInt32 {
  //For full list of WM_ constants reference: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants.WM
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
  }

  [Flags]
  public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : UInt32 {
    SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
    SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
    SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8,
    SMTO_ERRORONEXIT = 0x20
  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    WindowsMessages Msg,
    UIntPtr wParam,
    String lParam,
    SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags,
    UInt32 uTimeout,
    out UIntPtr lpdwResult
  );

}
```

and then calling it after the environment change with:

```
UIntPtr lRes;
NativeMsg.SendMessageTimeout(NativeMsg.HWND_BROADCAST, NativeMsg.WindowsMessages.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, "Environment", NativeMsg.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out lRes);
```

which appears to be working, might be some code flaws here as I gleamed most of it from pinvoke.net whose C# examples aren't working verbatim, but it does get the job done.